# Error message display the same error for all fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the same model error message for all fields on my register view. Here is my code for the Register Post method.

```
    [CaptchaMvc.Attributes.CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterRequest model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (Membership_BAL.UsernameExist(model.UserName.Username))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Usename is taken");

                return View();
            }

            if (Membership_BAL.EmailExist(model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address is taken");
                return View();
            }

            if (
                !Membership_BAL.CamparaEmailAddress(model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress,
                    model.EmailAddress.ComfirmEmailAddress))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address must match");
                return View();
            }


            Membership_BAL.Register(model);
            // TODO: Redirect use to profile page
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Error: captcha is not valid.";
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<fieldset>
    <legend> Register Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.UserName.Username)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.UserName.Username)
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.FirstName)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.FirstName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.LastName)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.LastName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.EmailAddress.ComfirmEmailAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.EmailAddress.ComfirmEmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.MathCaptcha()
           @TempData["Message"]
        </li>
    </ol>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">

</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: which error message is showing for all fields ?

Comment: @MillerKoijam, Which everyone returns true first. So if UsernameExist return true first it displays and if EmailExist return true it displays first

Comment: And you want to display all the error messages for all field that return false?

Comment: Error messages show only display when something returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quiet of hard without see the view or the model but i'm pretty sure that the problem it's related with this line

```
ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address must match");
```

The first parameter of this method receive the **field name** where you're going to display the error, and I see in your action that all the errors have the same name in the field.

You should change this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address must match");
```

For:

```
//Assuming that the field it's called Email    
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email Address must match");
```

And so on for each element in your model

Comment: The mode is a complex model. Like RegisterRequst.Username with Username being it's own class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         bool valid=true;
        if (Membership_BAL.UsernameExist(model.UserName.Username))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Usename is taken");

            valid=false;
        }

        if (Membership_BAL.EmailExist(model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address is taken");
             valid=false;
        }

        if (
            !Membership_BAL.CamparaEmailAddress(model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress,
                model.EmailAddress.ComfirmEmailAddress))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Email Address must match");
             valid=false;
        }
       if (!valid)
       {
          return view();
        }

        Membership_BAL.Register(model);
        // TODO: Redirect use to profile page
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear how this differs from the OP's code. How will this help?

Comment: ModelState will have all the errors. Where as the original code will have the first one to hit and return view. I removed repeated return view and check in a flag which will return view if it is false.